# Regex to match list of numbers

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match a very long list of numbers separated by commas and an optional space. It can't match a single integer. The list of numbers is approx 7000 bytes long bounded by text on either side.

```
12345 => don't match
12345,23456,34567,45678 => match
12345, 23456, 34567, 45678 => match
```

My current regex,

```
(?<!\.)(([0-9]+,)+[0-9]+)(?!\.)
```

causes a stack overflow. A few I have tried so far are:

```
([0-9,]+) => doesn't match with optional spaces
((\d+,[ ]?)+\d+) => worse than the original
[ ]([0-9, ]+)[ ] => can't be certain the numbers will be bounded by spaces
```

I'm using https://regex101.com/ to test the number of steps each regex takes, the original is approx 3000 steps.

Example (elided) string:

```
Processing 145363,145386,145395,145422,145463,145486 from batch 59
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d+(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*\d+)+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CLTP2j/2)

- `\d+` matches 1 or more digits
- `(?:...)+` matches 1 or more of following numbers separated by comma optionally surrounded with space/tab.

Answer (score 3):

```
(\d+,\s*)+\d+
```

`\d+,\s*` matches all the numbers with a comma followed by a space/nospace. However we need to lookout for the last number which doesn't have a "," as in the above group. So end it with last number by `\d+`.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
(?:\d+,\s*)+\d+
```

Breakdown:

```
(?:         # begin group
  \d+       #   digits
  ,\s*      #   ",", optional whitespace
)+          # end group, repeat
\d+         # digits (last item in the list)
```

Note that `\s` includes whitespace characters besides space and tab, most notably line breaks (`\n`). Use `[ \t]` in place of `\s` to prevent false positives, if your input requires it.

Answer (score 1):

you can get matches items with this regex:

```
(?<=,|^)\s*(\d+)\s*(?=,|$)
```